# How do I move from promise chaining to async/await multiple promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've searched a lot, tried many things but I can't come to a clean conclusion. I'm chaining a lot of Promises:

```
getInstalledComponents().call().then(response => {
    return {
        'installed_components': {
            'data': response
        }
    };
}).then((passed_data) => {
    return getDemosCategories().call().then(response => {
        return {...passed_data, ...{'demos_categories': response}};
    });
}).then((passed_data) => {
    return getDemosData().call().then(response => {
        return {...passed_data, ...{'demos_data': response}};
    });
}).then((passed_data) => {
});
```

I can't handle errors with this. I'd like to re-write this in such a manner that if one of them fails, all of them should fail and return.

I tried to `asy/await` each promise function, reached nothing. The promises that return the data I need are `getInstalledComponents, getDemosCategories, getDemosData` and each of them is a Promise-based AJAX call. It's basically resolved when the AJAX call comes back.

This doesn't look clean, nor useful. How can I re-write this to fit my requirements?

Comment: Have you tried to put a final `.catch(error){...}` after the last `.then()` ?

Comment: Handling errors is easy.  Just add `.catch()` at the end of your chain.  All errors in any of your promises will go to that.

Comment: and to run requests in parallel(now they are running in sequence but looks actually independent from each other) you may use `Promise.all`

Comment: @skyboyer That is exactly what I'd want. I want to parallelize them and I saw the syntax for `Promise.all` and tried but nothing worked. I'm actually having issues with writing the code itself.

Comment: @Weedoze I didn't. I'm still thinking about each promise being its own, not a chain, even if it's a chain. Never thought that's where all the promises' errors would go. How would I go about writing that in combination with a `Promise.all` which the other guy said parallelizes the requests?

Comment: Additionally, the fact that I have to keep sending data down the chain with `...` just doesn't feel right. Isn't there a better alternative where all promises get resolved and their data pulled together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing `Promise.all` we are able to parallelize requests:

```
Promise.all([
  getInstalledComponents().call(),
  getDemosCategories().call(),
  getDemosData().call()
])
.then(([installedComponents, demosCategories, demosData]) => ({
  "installed-categories": { data: installedComponents },
  "demos-categories": { data: demosCategories },
  "demos-data": {data: demosData}
}))
.catch(e => handleSomeErrorForAnyOfRequestsAbove(e))
```

Using `async/await` there still `Promise.all` will be needed:

```
const result = {};
try {
  const [installedComponents, demosCategories, demosData] = await 
    Promise.all([
      getInstalledComponents().call(),
      getDemosCategories().call(),
      getDemosData().call()
    ]);
  result["installed-components"] = installedComponents;
  result["demos-categories"] = demosCategories;
  result["demos-data"] = demosData;

} catch(e) {
  handleSomeErrorFromAnyOfRequestFailed();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were to simply put a catch block at the end of the last `then` it would catch errors in any of the functions.

```js
Promise.reject("firstFailed")
  .then(passedData => console.log("second") || passedData)
  .then(passedData => console.log("third")  || passedData)
  .then(passedData => console.log("fourth") || passedData)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

As you can see from the lack of console logs in the example above, first rejection stops the execution of any other `then` block

Comment: I see. It works. I was told that these could be paralellized with `Promise.all` and even tho I didn't specify, it's also what I want it to do. How would the syntax look with that in mind?